# Using multiprocessing to return multiple instances of a class inside a shared container class

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a very text/data heavy class method that I would like to break up across 36 cores using the Python multiprocessing package. Some of this is ported code from an R project I had do roughly the same. Using R it was relatively simple, I split the data frame into N (36 in this example) chunks and then ran a multiprocessing `foreach` loop over the function with the `foreach` loop index iterating across the broken up data frame.

In the code below, an instance of this class calls the bottom method `buildAllPatients` which extracts all the patent IDs (`patidList`) and passes them to the `buildPatientsFromPatid`. In turn, that method calls the private method `__populatePatient` for each entry of `patidList`. It creates an object of class `Patient`, executes a collection of getters and setters, and then returns the `Patient` object to add it to a container class instance called `Patients`.

I want to add a pool of workers inside the `buildPatientsFromPatid` method, essentially turning the for loop into some multiprocessing code. Each worker needs to return a unique `Patient` object having called `__populatePatient` and then return it to the shared `patients` object.

Essentially, this is helpful when there are somewhere in the order of 500,000 patient IDs, each turning into a Patient object and having a large number of getters and setters inside `__populatePatient`.

```
def __populatePatient(self, featureList, patidStr, indDF):
    #instantiates some objects, executes some getters and setters
    #returns the object patient to be added to the collector class Patients
    return patient

def buildPatientsFromPatid(self, patidList, featureList) -> Patients:
    # go through each entry of patidList, build a new Patient and assigned to a PatientsClass instance
    patients = Patients()

    #Iterate over each patient ID calling the private function
    #to build a Patient object, return it and add to the larger
    #Patients object
    for patidStr in patidList:
        patients.addPatient(self.__buildPatientFromPatid(patidStr, featureList))
    return patients


# This is called FIRST....
def buildAllPatients(self, featureList):
    patidList = self.ioDF.patid.unique()
    patients = self.buildPatientsFromPatid(patidList, featureList)
    return patients
```

**Update #1**
I wanted to add that this code is far away from the **main** function of the software. All examples I've found dealing with multiprocessing and object orientation have some element of multiprocessing executed from inside the **main** function.